# Keeping original instances after `groupby()`

Tags: pandas

What is the quickest way to keep the original instances after they get aggregated with `pandas.groupby`?

For example, given a dataframe `df`

```
  entries column  values
0  entry1      A     1.5 
1  entry2      A     1.3
2  entry3      A     0.6
3  entry4      B     0.7
4  entry5      B     0.5
5  entry6      C     0.5
6  entry7      C     1.3
7  entry8      C     1.7
```

and running `groupby` with `mean` as aggregation, I would like to obtain something like the following

```
  entries column    mean
0  entry1      A     1.333
1  entry2      A     1.333
2  entry3      A     1.333
3  entry4      B     0.6
4  entry5      B     0.6
5  entry6      C     1.666
6  entry7      C     1.666
7  entry8      C     1.666
```

i.e. the repeated property for all the original instances.

Comment: As per the suggested duplicate, you are looking for `transform`. E.g. something like: `df = df.assign(mean=df.groupby('column')['values'].transform('mean')).drop('values', axis=1)`

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for indeed. I didn't know about `.transform()`!